# How to select sequences using substrings from several dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have four dictionaries that contain substrings:

```
fw1={'PLAU_fw1':'CCCFFF','EPCAM_fw1':'GGGTTT','MIF_fw1':'HHHFFF'}
fw1_rc={'PLAU_fw1_rc':'cccfff','EPCAM_fw1_rc':'gggttt','MIF_fw1_rc':'hhhfff'}

fw2={'PLAU_fw2':'RRREEE','EPCAM_fw2':'OOOPPP','MIF_fw2':'KKKZZZ'}
fw2_rc={'PLAU_fw2_rc':'rrreee','EPCAM_fw2_rc':'oooppp','MIF_fw2_rc':'kkkzzz'}
```

and a fasta file:

```
>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:8051:1085
NNNNNNNNCCCFFFNNNNNGGGTTTNNNNNNN
>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:00000:1088
NNNNNNCCCFFFNNNNNrrreeeNNNNNNN
>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:16389:1090
NNNHHHFFFNNNNNNNOOOPPPNNNNNNN
>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:00000:1095
cccfffNNNNNNNKKKZZZNNNNNNN
```

I want to select sequences if two substrings are from specific dictionaries. The order of substrings is not important.

In other words, I want my code to select reads if one substring is from `fw1` and another one is from `fw2_rc` dictionary `OR` one substring is from `fw1_rc` and another one is from `fw2` dictionary.

This is my code; It selects correct reads but repeats outputs many times:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

count=0
with open('file.fasta','r') as f:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
        for k1,Fw1 in fw1.items():
            for k2,Fw1_rc in fw1_rc.items():
                for k3,Fw2 in fw2.items():
                    for k4,Fw2_rc in fw2_rc.items():


                        if Fw1 in record.seq and Fw2_rc in record.seq:
                            pos1 = record.seq.find(Fw1) + 1
                            pos2 = record.seq.find(Fw2_rc) + 1

                            if pos1 < pos2:
                                distance = pos2 - pos1
                            if pos1 > pos2:
                                distance = pos1 - pos2

                            print("sample_2")
                            print(record.id)
                            print(record.seq)
                            print(str(k1) + " : " + str(Fw1) + " - The position is " + str(pos1))
                            print(str(k4) + " : " + str(Fw2_rc) + " - The position is " + str(pos2))
                            print('\n')
                            

                        if Fw1_rc in record.seq and Fw2 in record.seq:
                            pos1 = record.seq.find(Fw1_rc) + 1
                            pos2 = record.seq.find(Fw2) + 1

                            if pos1 < pos2:
                                distance = pos2 - pos1
                            if pos1 > pos2:
                                distance = pos1 - pos2

                            print(record.id)
                            print(record.seq)
                            print(str(k2) + " : " + str(Fw1_rc) +  " - The position is " + str(pos1))
                            print(str(k3) + " : " + str(Fw2) +  " - The position is " + str(pos2))
                            print('\n')
                            count+=1
    print("The total number of reads that have both 21nt protein-specific sequences is " + str(count))
```

The desired output should be:

```
sample_2
MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:00000:1088
NNNNNNCCCFFFNNNNNrrreeeNNNNNNN
PLAU_fw1 : CCCFFF - The position is 7
PLAU_fw2_rc : rrreee - The position is 18

sample_2
MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:00000:1095
cccfffNNNNNNNKKKZZZNNNNNNN
PLAU_fw1_rc : cccfff - The position is 1
MIF_fw2 : KKKZZZ - The position is 14


The total number of reads that have both 21nt protein-specific sequences is 2
```

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer - I would say it would be great to not have it in regular expression since I am not familiar with it at all. In the future, I need to expand my code and I am not quite sure whether I can continue with the regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the counts and I reversed the key/value items in the dictionaries to allow lookups (that otherwise wouldn't have been possible for your desired results)

Also, I wasn't able to use `Bio` but just read from a text file but the changes to my code could be easily changed to the `Bio` `seq` and `id`.

```
import re

fw1={'PLAU_fw1':'CCCFFF','EPCAM_fw1':'GGGTTT','MIF_fw1':'HHHFFF'}
fw1 = dict(zip(fw1.values(), fw1.keys()))
fw1_rc={'PLAU_fw1_rc':'cccfff','EPCAM_fw1_rc':'gggttt','MIF_fw1_rc':'hhhfff'}
fw1_rc= dict(zip(fw1_rc.values(), fw1_rc.keys()))

fw2={'PLAU_fw2':'RRREEE','EPCAM_fw2':'OOOPPP','MIF_fw2':'KKKZZZ'}
fw2 = dict(zip(fw2.values(), fw2.keys()))
fw2_rc={'PLAU_fw2_rc':'rrreee','EPCAM_fw2_rc':'oooppp','MIF_fw2_rc':'kkkzzz'}
fw2_rc= dict(zip(fw2_rc.values(), fw2_rc.keys()))

one_upcase = '(' + '|'.join(fw1.keys()) + ')'
one_locase = '(' + '|'.join(fw1_rc.keys()) + ')'
two_upcase = '(' + '|'.join(fw2.keys()) + ')'
two_locase = '(' + '|'.join(fw2_rc.keys()) + ')'

with open('f1.txt', 'r') as f:
    _id = ''
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            _id = line[1:]
        else:
            if match := re.search(f'(?=.*{one_upcase})(?=.*{two_locase})', line):
                print(_id)
                print(line)
                for item in match.groups():
                    idx = 1 + line.index(item)
                    if item.isupper():
                        print(fw1[item], ': ', end='')
                    else:
                        print(fw2_rc[item], ': ', end='')
                    print(item, 'The position is', idx)
                print()
                    
            elif match := re.search(f'(?=.*{one_locase})(?=.*{two_upcase})', line):
                print(_id)
                print(line)
                for item in match.groups():
                    idx = 1 + line.index(item)
                    if item.isupper():
                        print(fw2[item], ': ', end='')
                    else:
                        print(fw1_rc[item], ': ', end='')
                    print(item, 'The position is', idx)
                print()
```

The ouput matches your output:

```
MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:00000:1088
NNNNNNCCCFFFNNNNNrrreeeNNNNNNN
PLAU_fw1 : CCCFFF The position is 7
PLAU_fw2_rc : rrreee The position is 18

MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:00000:1095
cccfffNNNNNNNKKKZZZNNNNNNN
PLAU_fw1_rc : cccfff The position is 1
MIF_fw2 : KKKZZZ The position is 14
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the solution not using regular expressions
(Also, I installed `Bio` to use it for this solution)

```
from Bio import SeqIO

# make values, (fasta seq), keys in dict and original keys now become values

fw1={'PLAU_fw1':'CCCFFF','EPCAM_fw1':'GGGTTT','MIF_fw1':'HHHFFF'}
fw1 = dict(zip(fw1.values(), fw1.keys()))

fw1_rc={'PLAU_fw1_rc':'cccfff','EPCAM_fw1_rc':'gggttt','MIF_fw1_rc':'hhhfff'}
fw1_rc= dict(zip(fw1_rc.values(), fw1_rc.keys()))

fw2={'PLAU_fw2':'RRREEE','EPCAM_fw2':'OOOPPP','MIF_fw2':'KKKZZZ'}
fw2 = dict(zip(fw2.values(), fw2.keys()))

fw2_rc={'PLAU_fw2_rc':'rrreee','EPCAM_fw2_rc':'oooppp','MIF_fw2_rc':'kkkzzz'}
fw2_rc= dict(zip(fw2_rc.values(), fw2_rc.keys()))

# store fasta substrings in lists
one_upcase = list(fw1.keys())
one_locase = list(fw1_rc.keys())
two_upcase = list(fw2.keys())
two_locase = list(fw2_rc.keys())


with open('fasta.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = 0
    for record in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
        _id = record.id
        seq = record.seq
        
        last = False
        for token_fw1 in one_upcase:
            if last == True:
                break
            for token_fw2_rc in two_locase:
                if token_fw1 in seq and token_fw2_rc in seq:
                    print(_id)
                    print(seq)
                    print(fw1[token_fw1], ':', token_fw1,
                          'in position', str(1+seq.index(token_fw1)))
                    print(fw2_rc[token_fw2_rc], ':', token_fw2_rc,
                          'in position', str(1+seq.index(token_fw2_rc)))
                    print()
                    last = True
                    break

        for token_fw1_rc in one_locase:
            if last == True:
                break
            for token_fw2 in two_upcase:
                if token_fw1_rc in seq and token_fw2 in seq:
                    print(_id)
                    print(seq)
                    print(fw1_rc[token_fw1_rc], ':', token_fw1_rc,
                          'in position', str(1+seq.index(token_fw1_rc)))
                    print(fw2[token_fw2], ':', token_fw2,
                          'in position', str(1+seq.index(token_fw2)))
                    print()
                    last = True
                    break
```

I didn't have a count here as I didn't know what it is you wanted to count.

I reversed the dictionaries (I think you created the dictionaries wrong) where the values, (fasta substrings), became the keys and the keys became the values. This permitted lookups in my solution:

`print(fw1_rc[token_fw1_rc] etc` and `print(fw2_rc[token_fw2_rc] etc`

(Two of the 4 times this lookup was done).

Also, a note, I said `token` here to mean the fasta substring.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your big help-now I am working on how to apply this code on multiple files and write output to several output files (differently named).